# Git - ignoring work done everywhere else in project except specific subdirectory of project?

Tags: git, version-control

if I have a project:

```
project/
    - A
    - B
    - C
```

If I want to isolate directory "A", how to I setup git such that I can ignore any other work that is done everywhere else besides "A"?

Explicitly, I want to ignore any file that is added or modified in "Project/B", "Project/C", and any file that is added or modified to "project/" in general, besides "A," obviously.

---

**Why I want to do this?**

The reason I want to do this is because the A, B, C don't depend on each-other. I want to avoid the possibility of merging a version of A that contains an older version of B to master, because from there on things get messy.

This mistake is obviously avoidable, but I want to setup my project so it's not possible.

---

**What I tried:**

What I thought of was to have the .gitignore file (located @ project/.gitignore) for every branch in this pattern:

```
# project/.gitignore of branch_name => DIR_NAME

/*
!/DIR_NAME/
```

This does not work because if I were to merge any branch into master, I would have conflicts with different project/.gitignore files. Again, I could probably figure out a way to avoid merging the .gitignore file every time I wanted to merge, but there has be a better way or official way to achieve the effect I'm looking for.

Comment: Is there a reason not to make A, B, and C separate git repositories?

Comment: @whydoubt Yes, essentially I'm creating a command line tool and folders A, B, C are independent functions of that tool. The tool also lives in the same directory in its own folder but calls upon the binaries created in A, B, C (just by path, so it's also not dependent on A, B, or C). So its all apart of the same project and would not make sense to create separate repositories.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore other projects, create a root-level `.gitignore` file and add the lines:

```
project/B/
project/C/
```

To verify that the other projects are ignored, you can use `git status --ignored`.

For more information, see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore.

Comment: I explained why this isn’t a perfect solution in my question

Comment: Shouldn't each project have the same .gitignore file?  What is a "project" in this context?